# Pass value To text box using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to access data from js file, and fetch the value in html text box, I'm not able get the result. here samle.js file and jsonhtml.html file

```js
{
"var1":"1";
"var2":"2";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
       setInterval(function () {
           $.getJSON("sample.js", function (data) {
               if (data.var1) {
                   $('#C1-Cycle').val(data.var1);
               }
               if (data.var2) {
                   $('#C2-Cycle').val(data.var2);
               }
           });
       }, 1000);
  });
})(jQuery);
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div>
<input type="text" id="C1-Cycle">
</div>
<hr>
<div>
<input type="text" id="C2-Cycle-Cycle">
</div>
</body
</html>
```

Comment: Put an alert `typeof data` right after the getJSON statement and see what you get and the JSON must be `{"var1":"1", "var2":"2"}`.

Comment: why you linking to jquery two times ?

Comment: firstly its not the valid json. The valid json is:   {
    "var1": "1",
    "var2": "2"
}

Comment: use the console...It will tell you invalid json

Comment: You need to parse your json like this JSON.parse(data);

Comment: Try `data[0].var1` instead of `data.var1`

Comment: @sehtaumesh I think you need to edit your comment as answer, so it can be market as resolution. To close this question, if it's possible add a jsfiddle example to show how it works

Comment: check working solution as: https://jsfiddle.net/5881pnqn/

Comment: Yes I do noticed and change the sample.js as  `{ "var1": "1", "var2": "2" }` still I'm not able get the result..

Comment: You need to use the parseJSON as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
       var winterval=setInterval(function () {

            $.getJSON("sample.js", function (result) {
               var data=$.parseJSON(result);

               if (data.var1) {
                   $('#C1-Cycle').val(data.var1);
               }
               if (data.var2) {
                   $('#C2-Cycle-Cycle').val(data.var2);
               }
            });

       }, 1000);
  });
```

But make sure, in your sample.js file the data like as:

{"var1":"1","var2":"2"}

Example as: https://jsfiddle.net/5881pnqn/2/

Comment: your fiddle file working, still set intervel function not working, also when I try to access data from  sample.js, It doesn't retrieve the result.. note: my sample.js file have just one line `{"var1":"1","var2":"2"}`

Comment: check now in jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/5881pnqn/2/   check in console interval working

Comment: my actual file looks like `$(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});           
var winterval=setInterval(function () {
   console.log(1);
    var dt='{"var1":":="Data_block_int".value[0]:","var2":":="Data_block_int".value[1]:"}';
               var data=$.parseJSON(dt);
               if (data.var1) {
                   $('#C1-Cycle').val(data.var1);
               }
               if (data.var2) {
                   $('#C2-Cycle').val(data.var2);
               }
       }, 1000);
  });`  **Data_block_int".value[0]**  value I'll get it from PLC machine.

Comment: that data block value is dynamic, It'll keep change I need to track the value in check box(every one sec), that's why I'm using set interval function, If set interval function work my html text box value also keep on change., now it's not running,

Comment: you mean setinterval not working and other is right ?

Comment: exactly. here is similar [example](https://jsfiddle.net/qn1v0L26/), in this example I've IO.html and I've just one line of it., It's working fine, I'm trying to do the same with multiple variable, that's why I'm using json parser, If I read the IO.html file every one sec and track that into textbox, then text box value will be dynamic., this is the vision

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function validate() {
            debugger;

            var name = document.myForm.name.value;
            if (name == "" || name == null) {
                document.getElementById("span1").innerHTML = "Please enter the Name";
                document.myForm.name.focus();
                document.getElementById("name").style.border = "3px solid red";
                return false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("span1").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("name").style.border = "3px solid green";
            }

            var age = document.myForm.age.value;
            var ageFormat = /^(([1][8-9])|([2-5][0-9])|(6[0]))$/gm;

            if (age == "" || age == null) {
                document.getElementById("span2").innerHTML = "Please provide Age";
                document.myForm.age.focus();
                document.getElementById("age").style.border = "3px solid red";
                return false;
            }
            else if (!ageFormat.test(age)) {
                document.getElementById("span2").innerHTML = "Age can't be leass than 18 and greater than 60";
                document.myForm.age.focus();
                document.getElementById("age").style.border = "3px solid red";
                return false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("span2").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("age").style.border = "3px solid green";
            }

            var password = document.myForm.password.value;
            if (document.myForm.password.length < 6) {
                alert("Error: Password must contain at least six characters!");
                document.myForm.password.focus();
                document.getElementById("password").style.border = "3px solid red";
                return false;
            }
            re = /[0-9]/g;
            if (!re.test(password)) {
                alert("Error: password must contain at least one number!");
                document.myForm.password.focus();
                document.getElementById("password").style.border = "3px solid red";
                return false;
            }
            re = /[a-z]/g;
            if (!re.test(password)) {
                alert("Error: password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z)!");
                document.myForm.password.focus();
                document.getElementById("password").style.border = "3px solid red";
                return false;
            }
            re = /[A-Z]/g;
            if (!re.test(password)) {
                alert("Error: password must contain at least one uppercase letter!");
                document.myForm.password.focus();
                document.getElementById("password").style.border = "3px solid red";
                return false;
            }
            re = /[$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-]/g;
            if (!re.test(password)) {
                alert("Error: password must contain at least one special character!");
                document.myForm.password.focus();
                document.getElementById("password").style.border = "3px solid red";
                return false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("span3").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("password").style.border = "3px solid green";

                createJSON();
            }
        }
        function createJSON() {
            debugger;
            var myData = $("#myTableData");
            var jsonData= JSON.stringify(myData.serializeArray());
            document.getElementById("span4").innerHTML = jsonData;
            console.log(jsonData);


        }
        function restrictCharacters(evt) {

            evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
            if (((charCode >= '65') && (charCode <= '90')) || ((charCode >= '97') && (charCode <= '122')) || (charCode == '32')) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }



        function clearForm() {
            document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("password").innerHTML = "";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myForm">
        <h2>Registration Form</h2>
        <form id="myTableData" name="myForm" onsubmit="return(validate());">

            <table>

                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name" class="information" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(event);" /></td>
                    <td><span id="span1"></span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="information" onkeypress="return event.charCode === 0 || /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode));" placeholder="Age" /></td>
                    <td><span id="span2"></span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="information" placeholder="Password" /></td>
                    <td><span id="span3"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" name="button" value="Proceed" onclick="validate();" />

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span id="span4"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```